# ffmpeg/Libavcodec couldn't find codec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

I want to make a transcoding video app from h.264 to h.265.
I have a problem with **libavcodec** library. I have this library in my project, all function is working, but when i'm trying to set codec :
`avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libx265");`
function couldn't find it. Hovewer, when i give "hevc" instead of "libx265" function is working, but it's not the same.
Please for help :)

Answer (score 3):

### There is no decoder named libx265

libx265 is only an encoder.

### FFmpeg has a native, built-in HEVC/H.265 decoder

It is named *hevc*. You don't have to do anything special to include or enable it.

There are also several hardware accelerated HEVC decoders that may be available for your system: hevc_cuvid, hevc_mediacodec, hevc_qsv, hevc_rkmpp, and hevc_v4l2m2m.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has implemented codecs (lets call them builtin) and wrappers to third party codecs. It seems/could be that the h265 codec is just a wrapper, that means you have to install a h265 decoder. Besides, did you specify the h265 codec when you configured ffmpeg? Did you build it yourself or pre build via package manager?

Try 'ffmpeg -decoders' at the command line and search for h265.